# Why don't I get a source window using realgud:gdb?

Tags: microsoft-windows, gdb, realgud

using GNU Emacs 25.2.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) and realgud 20171006.1840 (from marmalade), I can't use realgud for debugging with gdb: I start it as described in the docu:

```
M-x load-library RET realgud RET
realgud:gdb
```

In the "Start like this"-Prompt, I just add my binary:

```
Run gdb (like this): /cygwin64/bin/gdb.exe ../build/tests/tests.exe
```

... and I get a gdb command window. So far so good. The realgud documentation mentiones, that in order to get a source window with gdb, I have to run the `start` command, which I do:

```
Reading symbols from c:/Users/me/Documents/Projects/p/build/tests/tests.exe...done.
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x1004010fa: file /cygdrive/c/Users/me/Documents/Projects/p/tests/main.cc, line 18.
Starting program: /cygdrive/c/Users/me/Documents/Projects/p/build/tests/tests.exe 
[New Thread 3528.0x360c]
[New Thread 3528.0x1078]

Temporary breakpoint 1, 0x00000001004010fa in main (ac=1, av=0xffffcbe0)
    at /cygdrive/c/Users/me/Documents/Projects/p/tests/main.cc:18
18  {
(gdb)
```

But no source window appears. I have no gui element whatsoever: No breakpoints in my sources, no toolbar icons - just the bare gdb prompt. What's wrong there?